# Binomial basis of polynomial ring

Tags: binomial-coefficients, lie-algebras

The polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has a basis given by the "binomial powers" $\binom{x}{0}, \binom{x}{1}, \binom{x}{2}, \ldots$ where we define
$$ \binom{x}{k} = \frac{1}{k!} x (x - 1) \ldots (x - k + 1).$$
Given $n, m \geq 0$, is there a nice expression for the product of two of these basis elements $\binom{x}{n} \binom{x}{m}$ in terms of the binomial basis?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would probably not count that as a "nice" expression, but if its the nicest suggested I guess that's the way it is. I was certainly hoping for something cleaner and more symmetric.

Comment: If you are hoping for more you could try to improve your question by saying more precisely what you mean by "nice" and  "clean" (more than symmetric I suppose).

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's hard to say what I'm looking for when I don't know what possibilities are even out there. I was expecting that, as with many identities involving binomial coefficients, there would be many many ways of writing this expansion. Is there truly no room for such a concrete but "soft" question?

Comment: I think there is room for such a question. You could perhaps also try to give more context here, i.e., why you are interested in this question, where it comes from, and what you could do with it. This would also make the question then more "concrete".

Comment: @Joppy: I think I could grasp your request for better symmetry: I added my answer in the post where your question has been diverted to.